# I want all columns(<td></td>) in a <table></table> have the equal length, how to achieve this?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

How to achieve it with CSS or HTML?

```
 <table class="banner"><tr><td>If you need many results, then post your task as piecework here. You only need to pay qualified results.
  </td>
 <td>Make money by doing piecework</td></tr>
 <tr><td><a href="publish.php">POST PIECEWORK FOR FREE</a><br/></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: The overall width of the table is equally divided among all columns.

Comment: By length, do you mean width or height? Or both? @jjj - we were all beginners once.

Comment: @jjj: Sadly, on SO a high reputation can also mean "asks a lot of questions" which is exactly the case here -- he's only given 1 answer but asked 175 questions.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley...it is ok .. the important thing is  that he is learning

Comment: @Bryan: I disagree with the "sadly". Well-put questions are definitely worth all the reputation that they produce. In fact the questions are even more important than the answers, because without questions none of us would be here.

Comment: I agree questions are important and beginners should be embraced. In fact, the whole reason I participate is to help beginners. However, I think awarding points for questions gives a misleading reputation score. jjj's confusion is a perfect illustration of that point. I trust answers from someone with 1k of reputation all from answers more than someone with 1k of reputation for only asking questions. But I digress; this is better discussed on meta. I just don't want Steven to think I'm critical of him because he's learning. Quite the contrary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`table-layout`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) property here...

```
table { table-layout: fixed; }
table td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm.. i don't know maybe this  is better..!

Comment: I updated answer to use overflow hidden on the `td` so that long strings don't break outside the table.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS:

```
td{overflow:hidden;width:200px;}
```

Comment: and add td cssclass to all tds..an other thing don't put to banner class any width..!

Comment: You don't need classes.  His question was only how to make the columns the same width.

Comment: @ austin cheney .... there is many ways to do that.. and this is a way to do it..!!

Comment: This is ineffective when the contents are larger than 200px.  For instance, a string that is longer than 200px will expand the table column.

Comment: On the other hand, using `table-layout` will work regardless of cell content (see my answer).

Comment: @Josh, no a long string will not expand the visible width of the table cell.  Notice how I included the overflow:hidden property.

Comment: @austin Sorry `<table border="1"><tr><td>ThisIsMeProvingYouWrongButDontBeOffendedItHappensSometimes</td></tr></table>`

Comment: @Josh You are still ignoring the overflow:hidden property, and the border attribute has been deprecated for nearly a decade.  If you are going to try to prove somebody wrong please get your facts straight, listen, and do not use an example that is itself faulty and outdated.

Comment: @Austin The `border` attribute is not deprecated.  Try my markup with your CSS and you will see that it extends way beyond 200px, which means you are **wrong**.  My facts are straight, wise guy.  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you can use the **width** property. This can be done inline or as part of a stylesheet. For some more CSS for tables, check out [CSS Styling Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) from w3schools.

```
td {
    width:200px;
}

<td style="width:200px;">
```

Or, in HTML, check out the **colgroup** tag, like this:

```
<colgroup>
    <col width="200px" />
</colgroup>
```

I personally use the colgroup the most.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
table { width:100% }
td { width:20% }
```

(assuming you have 5 td's per row. If you have three, put width 33%, if you have 2 put 50% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width (CSS or inline if you wish) to be the same percent value for each column (ideally with a total of 100%).  This will allow progressive scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` property for the `td` selector.  However, possibly you want to discriminate one table over the other.  In that case, you can classify your 'equal-width' table like this:

```
<table class="equal_width_columns">
    <tr><td>one</td><td>onetwothree</td></tr>
</table>

<table> <!-- just a regular table -->
    <tr><td>one</td><td>onetwothree</td></tr>
</table>
```

with css like this:

```
table.equal_width_colums * td { width: 300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for this myself. But in my case, the table count was not fixed, hence giving exact percentage was not an option. Found another solution at

http://freachable.net/2007/11/02/AutomaticEqualWidthColumnsInHTMLTables.aspx

Give the cells a very small width. The cells will scale up to fill the available width.

```
table tr td { width:5%; }
```